# Openshift - Warning! Could not start io.js application

Tags: openshift

I tried to install slackin in openshift but could not start the application as following error:

```html
remote: npm WARN EPACKAGEJSON slackin@0.5.1 No repository field.
remote: npm WARN EPACKAGEJSON slackin@0.5.1 No license field.
remote: CLIENT_RESULT: io.js modules installed.
remote: Preparing build for deployment
remote: Deployment id is c19746a3
remote: Activating deployment
remote: CLIENT_MESSAGE: Starting io.js application...
remote: CLIENT_RESULT: Warning! Could not start io.js application!
remote: -------------------------
remote: Git Post-Receive Result: failure
remote: Activation status: failure
remote: Activation failed for the following gears:
remote: 5604ef6589f5cf3a2000003f (Error activating gear: CLIENT_ERROR: Failed to execute: 'control start' for /var/lib/openshift/5604ef6589f5cf3a2000003f/iojs
remote: #<IO:0x00000001b4e3c0>
remote: #<IO:0x00000001b4e348>
remote: )
remote: Deployment completed with status: failure
remote: postreceive failed
```

What kind of error is it? Thanks for your help.